# Full Calendar - Rails - Adding Custom CSS Classes to Events

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, fullcalendar

I'm showing Appointments on a calendar. I'm looking to add a class to the event so that I can change their background colour based on the status of the Appointment.

```
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var user_id = '<%= params[:id] %>';
    var eventsPath = "/users/" + user_id + "/appointments.json";

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          editable: false,
          handleWindowResize: true,
          displayEventEnd: false,
          firstDay: 1,
          allDaySlot: false,
          columnFormat: 'ddd',
          scrollTime: '12:00:00',
          eventBackgroundColor: '#505B75',
          eventBorderColor: '#505B75',
          header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
          height: 650,
          slotDuration: "00:15:00",
          slotEventOverlap: false,
          loading: function(bool){
              if (bool) 
                  $('#loading').show();
              else 
                  $('#loading').hide();
          },
          events: eventsPath,
          allDay: false,

      });
  });
</script>
```

Here's the events path (JSON)

```
json.array! User.find(params[:user_id]).appointments do |appointment|
  json.extract! appointment, :id, :business_title
  json.title appointment.business_title
  json.start appointment.starts_at
  json.className 'boobs'
  json.end appointment.starts_at + 30.minutes
  json.url appointment_url(appointment, format: :html)
end
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can add styles to specific events through an eventRender callback. The event has already rendered, so you'll need to alter the style / add a class to the element directly.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    eventRender: eventRenderCallback,
    ...
});

function eventRenderCallback(event, element){
    element.addClass(event.className);
}

<style>
    .myClass{
        background-color:red !important;
    }
</style>
```